# How to Crop Long Images into Segments on Android to Prevent Quality Loss?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I'm developing an Android application where displaying long images, like product details, is required. I've noticed that when I display such elongated images in one go, there is a noticeable reduction in image quality

To tackle this issue, I'm considering cropping these lengthy images into multiple segments and then displaying them separately. My expectation is that this approach will help me preserve the original image quality. I've looked into using the Bitmap class for image manipulation, but I'm curious if there's a more efficient method or any existing libraries that can perform this task more effectively

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.